# When run npm start , the following error shows: can not find module in "..../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js'

Tags: reactjs, compilation

When run npm start, the following error shows:  can not find module in "..../node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js', didn't change any code after "npx create-react-app".

[image]

Comment: Copy-pasted error reports are preferred to images of error reports as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try delete node_modules and package-lock.json then npm install or yarn again